# is there a way to play two sources ( a wav file and a samson meteorite recording) at the same time?

Tags: raspbian, usb, audio

So I am fairly new to raspberry pi. I have a raspberry pi 2 connected to amp+ and to two speakers. I would like to play a wav file in loop while the samson meteorite usb mic is getting sounds and playing through the same speakers. I got the wav file working and the mic working. But when I try to play them with aplay at the same time I get a message that a resource or device is busy. Is it possible to this on aplay? Is there anyway I can play two sources at the same time?
For the wav file i use the code : aplay /home/pi/music/Gunseli.wav
and for the recording coming to the speakers: 
arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f cd | aplay

Thanks